# Create pop up after a week

Tags: excel, vba

I am having a column of dates and I want after a week of each date is passed a pop up to be displayed.

I don't know anything about macros. Do I have to run the macro every time I open the document?

This is something I made so far:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
 Dim i As Long
 For i = 1 To Rows.Count
   if Cells(i, 1).Value<(TODAY()+7) And Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, 1).Value) then
     MsgBox Cells(i,1).Value + "Needs your attention!"
     Cells(i, 1).Font.Color = vbRed
   End If
 Next i
End Sub
```

Didn't test it yet though.

Comment: Do you want it to run every time you open the document? What is the process which your sheet is being populated with new dates?

Comment: Hi, I found `Private Sub Workbook_Open()` which runs whenever I open the document. The sheet is populated by hand. Question, do I need to have a `.xlsm` document and not a `xlsx` in oder to run the vba commands?

Comment: Yes. it must be xlsm

Comment: @George it doesn't need to be a `xlsm` file to run the macros. To run them you will need macros to be enabled. However to save the file and the macros you will need it to be either a `xlsm` file or a `xlsb`. All other file types will only save the worksheets and you'll lose all your macros once you close the workbook.

Answer (score 1):

From a usability point of view it is not advisable to use a pop up for each and every overdue item. The only thing you will achieve with that is to annoy the poor sod who opens the workbook after a three-week vacation and who will have to click OK in 243 message boxes.

As an alternative approach you may want to consider conditional formatting to highlight overdue items in the sheet. Conditional formatting is easily done and is designed for that job.

With the same logic you use for the conditional formatting you can establish in if any item is overdue and then use VBA to pop up ONE SINGLE message box, advising the user to take care of the highlighted data in the spreadsheet.

Of course, this can be done completely without VBA, using conditional formatting in a cell in the spreadsheet to show a message while any item is overdue.

The latter will work in any Excel version, with any file type and does not require macro-enabled files or any of the hoops involved with macros.

Please design your spreadsheets with the end user in mind.

Edit after comment:

Consider the following screenshot:

[image]

Highlighting in column A is done with conditional formatting using a formula `=A5<TODAY()-7`

Column B has this formula in B5 copied down: `=A5<=TODAY()-7`, which is the same formula used in the conditional format.

Cell B2 has a formula that counts the "true" values in B5 and below and displays a message if there is at least one TRUE value. The formula is

`=IF(COUNTIF(B5:B10,TRUE),"There are "&COUNTIF(B5:B10,TRUE)&" overdue items in the list","")`

This is just a rough outline. Shift the message cell to column A, hide column B, so the user does not see the TRUE/FALSE stuff, but only a message about things to take care of and the things highlighted.

Comment: You are correct, I removed the msgBox from the loop. But how can I achieve the same result wthout vba?

Comment: I've edited my answer to include details about a non-VBA approach.

Comment: However this only highlights the values, there is no pop up.

Comment: in lieu of a pop up there is text in cell B2. It will only show if items need TLC.  Make it big, bold and red so it will be noticed. If you really want a message box, then you need VBA, with all the drawbacks of macro enabled files. Your call.